# Best way to present groups of names html vs css

Tags: html, css, joomla3.0

I have a list of 40 names, with titles and other bits of information, kinda like a year book photo page, but with out the photos.  In the past I used HTML tables to do this, but wonder is that the best way?  I'm using joomla and I could learn to use css for this.

Any suggestions?

d

Comment: Tables work fine, but if you want different center an image at the top of a box and put some text below the image in the box.  If you want, make the box hidden to make it look better.

Comment: How do I use css in an article with joomla?

Answer (score 0):

You should use HTML to show this information. CSS is purely for styling the table.
Take a look at [this Table guide](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/) which runs you through making the table in HTML then styling it using CSS.

CSS-Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a table structure, a table will be just fine, just never use table for your layout, that only makes your code messy and unreadable.